# How do I check the version of ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid

Trying to implement multi select features with `rowSelection: "multiple"`

But, I believe that seems to be not happening with my current version of my ag-grid in the project. So want to update it. Any help to check the version number of ag-grid ?

Comment: did you install with npm?

Comment: in order to update the version you need to update the version in package.json file and have to install it using -npm install.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed ag-grid with npm, there will be new folder called ag-grid inside node_modules. The relative path is "node_modules/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js" You can see which version is installed on this file.

Comment: Please check your `packages.json` file.

Comment: @jabu.hlong Sometimes package.json is notated with something like "^20.0.0" so the exact version cannot be seen there. the min.js file referenced by Zahid displays the current version on line 1 of the file.

Comment: @Kaorie you can use `npm list <package-name>` otherwise look in you `packages-lock.json`

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the minified version of the ag grid file that you import a.k.a. ag-grid-enterprise.min.js, there is commented out section right at the top. The version number should be listed there. You should see a comment section similar to the one I've pasted below:

```
/**
 * @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules - Advanced Data Grid / Data Table supporting Javascript / React / AngularJS / Web Components
 * @version v25.1.0
 * @link http://www.ag-grid.com/
 * @license Commercial
 */
// @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules v25.1.0
```

Hopefully this helps!